# Laravel routes are not working on production server 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, server

I have a laravel project, which is working fine on the local machine, where I have it set up on homestead, but when I have uploaded project to the production server on namecheap, none of the links or routes are working, I only get the index page open with no style, and if I click on any of the links I get 500 error. 
I have follow the suggested steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868393/laravel-shared-hosting-routes-not-working-properly/46409411#46409411):

So, my laravel project directory is in the same level as public_html, as well as public directory from my laravel project. They are all in the same directory level. And I have changed the paths in the `index.php` file:

```
require __DIR__.'/mariva/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/mariva/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Then, I have changed the server.php inside the laravel project directory:

```
require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/index.php';
```

Permission were set apparently by the namecheap customer service, but I still get 404 error for all my css and js files, as well as when clicking on some html links on my page.

In the view file I am calling my css files like this:

```
<!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="{{ asset('css/material-kit/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{ asset('css/material-kit/css/material-kit.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="{{ asset('css/landing-page.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And js file the same way:

```
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/jquery.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/bootstrap.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/material.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- Control Center for Material Kit: activating the ripples, parallax effects, scripts from the example pages etc -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/landing-page/material-kit.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Not sure how can I fix that?

**Update**

I have managed to fix the css and js issue of not opening the files, I have moved the files to the wrong directory by mistake. But I still can't get any links on the page to work?

In my view I have links like this one:

```
<a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a>
```

And when clicking on them I get `404` error.

Comment: Is your server VPS? Do your .htaccess work?

Comment: are you deploy in share hosting or server dedicated?

Comment: I am deploying on shared server

Answer (score 2):

the problem may be in the trusted hosts

try setting this in your `.env`

```
APP_URL=http://
```

Comment: on the production env, not setting the APP_URL will result in 404 routes, that's weird but true!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Laravel project in shared hosting which is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868393/laravel-shared-hosting-routes-not-working-properly/46409411#46409411).

After you succeed thru all 7 steps your project should work fine on server.

Also add this to your `.htacces` file in `public_html`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Have you copied all content of public folder from Laravel to hosting folder `public_html`? Don't override `index.php` and `.htacess` files.

Comment: I have copied all the content from public laravel folder to public_html folder, except for the .htacess file. I have modifed the existin .htacess file in public_html folder and added code you suggested, so it looks like this now: ```DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm parking-page.html

<IfModule mod_suphp.c> 
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/marigxwy/public_html 
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]```  But I still don't get any css and js links open.

Comment: Remove all code from `.htacces ` file and add just mine code

Answer (score 0):

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laravel51/public/
```

# change above to your site i.e.,  RewriteBase /whatever/public/

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In .htaccess file has to change