# Laravel 5.6 deployed application routes give 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos

I have deployed an application to an apache server and it works fine, well only the homepage. As soon as I try to go to a route I get the Not found error in my request log I see `GET /users 404`

My virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv ENVPHP acc
    ServerName someurlblabla.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/projectname/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/projectname/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file is just the default laravel one with apache being able to access and read it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I'm a bit lost since I don't get any errors in my log and I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: [Laravel routes are not working on production server 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678300/laravel-routes-are-not-working-on-production-server-404-error)

Comment: php artisan route:clear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868393/laravel-shared-hosting-routes-not-working-properly/46409411#46409411

Comment: @niklaz I've done this

Comment: Make sure you have the mod rewrite enabled in your apache: sudo a2enmod rewrite

Comment: @Troyer it's a centos distribution how do I do this?

Comment: @Michael did you restart the apache?

Comment: @niklaz yes I did restart apache

Comment: You can check if mod_rewrite is enabled running: httpd -M

Answer (score 1):

what's about this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv ENVPHP acc
    ServerName someurlblabla.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/projectname/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/projectname">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't wanna hear this, but switching to Nginx will solve a lot of these problems , and your site will run faster. That's why Laravel Valet uses Nginx.